# Moments of linear combinations of normally distributed variables

Tags: self-study, expected-value

So I have this problem I have to solve for my homework for my Linear Regression Class that is due tomorrow and I honestly dont know where to start with this problem.

"Suppose to have $X\sim N(0,1)$ $Y=3-2X$ and $Z=2-X$

Find $E(Y)$ $E(Z)$ $Var(Y)$ $Var(Z)$"

I think the fact that it is a normal distribution might have something to do with solving this but other than that I am confused...

Comment: Everybody who posts a question here needs help with a statistics question.  Please choose a title that relates to the specific statistical problem you have. The normality of $X$ is irrelevant; the problem deals with basic properties of [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) and [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) only.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, I'll just give hints.  Remember that E means "expected value".  Now, think about what the expected value for 3 - 2X and 2 - X would be.

Further hint: The normal distribution is not a key point here.

Comment: so would E(Y) = 3-2(0)=2 and E(Z)= 2-0=2 since E(X) = 0 ?
and based off that the var(y) = 4 and var(z)=1

Comment: Slight mistake 3-2(0)= 3 ;)

Answer (score 0):

"Suppose to have X~N(0,1) Y=3-2X and Z=2-X

Find E(Y) E(Z) Va(Y) Var(Z)"

I'll show you how to solve one of each and then you should be able to do the rest.

\begin{align}
E(Y)&=E(3-2X)\\
&=E(3)-E(2X)\\
&=3-2\times E(X)\\
&=3-2\times0\\
&=3
\end{align}

Likewise
\begin{align}
Var(Y)&=Var(3-2X)\\
&=Var(3)+Var(-2X)\\
&=0+(-2)^2\times Var(X)\\
&=0+(-2)^2\times1\\
&=0+4\times1\\
&=4
\end{align}

The calculations for E(Z) and Var(Z) follow similarly.